# Calling boost::asio::read() in a thread blocks calling thread or process?

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, network-programming, boost-asio

I'm quite new to network programming and I'm writing a program that should accept many TCP connections and receive data from them. To make things go parallel, the agent should read data from each socket in a new thread. I decided to use `boost::asio` instead of raw *nix sockets to make things simpler. Though this seems to be a wrong decision...

I wonder if I calling `boost::asio::read` or `boost::asio::read_some` blocks only its calling thread or blocks process? Yes I should write my own small test and see results myself, but I have no access to my Linux box right now. Just thinking about code that I should write tomorrow at university.

So if it blocks the process, what's correct way of implementing a server/client architecture that accepts many clients at same time?

**Notes:**

1. I'm having difficulties about design decisions. Any suggestion is appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The read and read_some calls are both blocking, and will only block the current thread for Linux and Win32 (and probably most others, just don't have direct expericence).

You might want to look into using async_read instead though if you are having a large number of incoming connections, as you might acctually do better performance wise using a smaller number of threads than number of connections. Boost does provide examples of using the thread pool to handle client connections.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I read the `HTTP Server 3` example in documentation. It's too complex for my needs! I'm gonna switch to ZMQ instead.